# How can I make the proxy squid to use itself a http_proxy?

Tags: proxy, squid

Attention: Here `proxy` is ambiguious term as squid should be both the proxy server and a proxy client.

On a system I can access resource on the http/https protocol only via a proxy. I have a two systems

- system 1: is allowed access to the proxy
- system 2: is not allowed access to the proxy

Since system 2 needs to download some packages and I cannot directly use the proxy I envisioned that I can setup the `squid` proxy server on *system 1* such as that it can hand throught the traffic.

I struggle however to tell the squid proxy on system 1 to send out the http/https request via the proxy itself?

I have set the environment of the squid proxy server daemon to contain this info (via the file `/etc/sysconfig/squid`)

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.network:3128
ftp_proxy=http://proxy.network:3128
https_proxy=http://proxy.network:3128
```

this however does not seem to trigger squid to actually use this proxy setup

The `/var/log/squid/access.log` shows this:

```
1579858778.927   1479 172.22.0.252 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/000 0 GET http://lwn.net/ - HIER_DIRECT/66.228.47.22 -
1579858786.871   5295 172.22.0.252 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1368 CONNECT lwn.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/66.228.47.22 -
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#How_do_I_configure_Squid_forward_all_requests_to_another_proxy.3F

it was necessary to put those three lines in the `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file:

```
cache_peer proxy.company.de   parent  3128 3130
prefer_direct off
nonhierarchical_direct off
```